# How much carbon in the surface ocean

Tags: science-fair-project

The natural flux of carbon into the atmosphere is about 90 Gt per year. Humans are adding additional carbon dioxide each by burning fossil fuels. Some of it is absorbed by the oceans. The residence time of carbon in the surface ocean with respect to input is about 11 years. How much carbon in the surface ocean?